# Printing data in Alamofire request

Tags: ios, swift, http, alamofire

I am trying to print the data returned from an alamofire post request in swift like so:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://blablabla.com/test1", parameters: ["operand1": "123"]).response { request, response, data, error in
        print(request)
        print(response)
        print(data, radix: 16)
        print(error)
    }
```

but when I try to print data it doesn't print a string a string, instead it prints:
<796570>

I am a bit new to swift so I don't really know if there is a way or a reason for this.

Comment: print(response.result.value!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the raw server response which is in `NSData` type. You can make use of some built-in serializers such as [`.responseString()`](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#response-string-handler) in order to convert that into user readable value:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://blablabla.com/test1", parameters: ["operand1": "123"]).responseString { response in
  print("Response String: \(response.result.value)")
}
```

You can check out other serializers in the Alamofire [documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#response-serialization).